# MonoTouch AOT compiler not constructing Dictionary types in generic classes

Tags: c#, generics, xamarin.ios, aot

In MonoTouch, when creating a generic type that has a Dictionary that uses the type's generic type parameter for its values' type, the AOT compiler doesn't construct the required Dictionary type, resulting in a runtime error on an iOS device when it tries to invoke the JIT compiler.

```
public class Foo<T>
{
    private Dictionary<int, T> d = new Dictionary<int, T>();
    ...
}

var foo = new Foo<string>(); // Runtime error.
```

There is a work-around ([posted on the Catalysts blog](http://www.catalysts.cc/blog/monotouch-and-our-first-experiences/?lang=en)) that involves explicitly declaring any constructed types required elsewhere in the program:

```
var x = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

But that's a bit messy. **Is there a better work-around?**

Also, it seems to me that all the information is there at compile time, so the AOT compiler should be able to construct the required types. Is this therefore a compiler feature that is feasible (and we could possibly get in a future release)?

Comment: Have you filed a bug about this? http://bugzilla.xamarin.com is your friend. If you report it, it will likely be fixed in a future release unless it is a knob limitation of generics.

Comment: @Krumelur I was guessing it was probably a known limitation, so was just after a better work-around, but I suppose I'll file a bug report too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has now been fixed, so no workaround is required:

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=5316